# Conditional Mapping Framework in Java

Tags: java, mapping

My requirement was to map one Java Object to another. But this was conditional mapping as follows

```
// Create Y from data in X
// If X has a=A and b=B then set p=P in Y else set p=P'
// If X has c that starts with "CC" then set q=Q in Y else set q=Q'
// so on
```

I explored Dozer & MapStruct, but did not find them apt for supporting above conditions without polluting code with lot of annotations.

Is there any library that cleanly abstracts out such conditional mappings or rules. I mean, some framework that executes rules in a sequence and finally ends up creating Y from X

```
// Here ChainOfTransformers may be configuration driven transformation logic
ExpectedLibrary.map(SourceEntity, DestinationEntity, ChainOfTransformers)
```

Please point me to open source units that I can explore

Comment: Since the logic you obviously do have seems to be quite complicated, why not take the generated output of e.g. MapStruct and enrich it with your own logic?

Answer (score 1):

When using MapStruct, you might take a look at [decorators](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#customizing-mappers-using-decorators) and [after-mapping](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after) callbacks. Both allow you to perform additional mapping logic from hand.

Personally I think you are better of by implementing these routines using plain Java code instead of some kind of "configured rules".